# Why is the easy-autcomplete not working on Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, easyautocomplete

It has been several days now that i've been trying to make work the easy-autocomplete package with my Rails 6 application.

I followed [this tutorial](https://joelc.io/dynamic-autocomplete-rails-6).

I tried some solutions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273132/rails-6-how-to-use-easyautocomplete/62255114#62255114) but it still doesn't work.

In all my attempts the error displayed on the web console is: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).easyAutocomplete is not a function`.

Here is my `application.js`:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("bootstrap");
// Stylesheets
require("../stylesheets/main.scss");

require("easy-autocomplete");
```

I don't need to `require('jquery')` since it's included with the Bootstrap package. I use JQuery functions all over my app and haven't got any errors.

My `application.scss`:

```
 @import 'easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete';
 @import "variables";

* {
  font-family: $syne-font
}
```

And my custom js code:

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  var options = {
    data: ["otto", "hans", "paula"],
  };

  $("#city_search").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

Comment: Hello, did you finally find the solution ? Best regards

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the *easy-autocomplete* lib is not maintained anymore.

I did find a workaround by using the *webpack-jquery-ui* lib, here's an example of implementation:

*app/javascript/packs/application.js*

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("bootstrap");

// Stylesheets
require("../stylesheets/main.scss");

global.$ = require("jquery");

require("webpack-jquery-ui");
require("webpack-jquery-ui/css");

$(function () {
  $(".my-input-automcompleted").autocomplete({
    source: "/autocomplete",
  });
});
```

But IMHO it's better to use [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/introduction) and the [stimulus-autocomplete](https://github.com/afcapel/stimulus-autocomplete) lib now !

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you install jQuery using the yarn and also do he configuration in the config/webpack/environment.js. once done require the jQuery as expected from the tutorial.

Try it and it should work.

Comment: I tried installing jQuery as said in the tutorial but it doesn't work.